# Select data from many-to-many table in which a column's values matches all given values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named SUPPLIER_CATEGORY as a many-to-many relation between SUPPLIER and CATEGORY tables. What I want is to get the SUPPLIER_IDs from SUPPLIER_CATEGORY table which matches all the CATEGORY_IDs that was given.

For an example consider the following table

```
SUPPLIER_ID    CATEGORY_ID

101                1
101                2
102                1
102                3
103                1
103                2
103                3
```

If I want to get the SUPPLIER_IDs with CATEGORY_ID 1 and 2. The query should return SUPPLIER_IDs 101 and 103 but not 102 tho it has the CATEGORY_ID = 1. Because it does not contain CATEGORY_ID 2. Hope it makes sense.

**EDIT:**

**NOTE:** CATEGORY_IDs can be more than 2 numbers.

Thanks.

Comment: provide sample data and your expected output in table format

Comment: @codeworks tried. but it returns records even if a single CATEGORY_ID is found. the table has 14 records with CATEGORY_ID 1 and 12 records with CATEGORY_ID 2. When I use IN it returns 14 records where it should return less

Comment: @fa06 provided table is the sample data and the output is just SUPPLIER_ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the given sample data, below would be the query.

```
select supplier_id
from <tableName>
where category_id in (1, 2)
group by supplier_id
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: On what basis you need supplier id for given input, Or let say distinct category_id in table is 1,2,3...5, do you need suppliers with all category id or only with select category id

Comment: I want supplier id for category ids that will be passed as parameters

Comment: above query would still work, you have to paramterize supplier_id and count of supplier_id... you have to pass one more parameter with count of supplier id's.

Comment: This solution works perfectly. I just needed to understand HAVING clause. Thanks you for the quick and easy response.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

```
select SUPPLIER_ID from tablename where CATEGORY_ID in (1,2)
group by SUPPLIER_ID  having count(distinct CATEGORY_ID)=2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @catIds varchar(max)='1,2'
DECLARE @SplitOn CHAR = ','

-------------- spliting all CATEGORY_ID ---- 
DECLARE @RtnTable TABLE (catId int )
DECLARE @Count int
SET @Count = 1
WHILE (CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@catIds)>0)

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @RtnTable (catId)

SELECT
    Value = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@catIds,1,CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@catIds)-1)))

    SET @catIds = SUBSTRING(@catIds,CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@catIds)+LEN(@SplitOn),LEN(@catIds))
Set @Count = @Count + 1
END

INSERT INTO @RtnTable (catId)

SELECT
    Value = LTRIM(RTRIM(@catIds))

-------------------------------------------------


--------------- main part ---------------
SELECT  [SUPPLIER_ID]      
  FROM [EmployeeDb].[dbo].[SUPPLIER_CATEGORY]
  WHERE CATEGORY_ID in(SELECT * from @RtnTable)
  GROUP BY [SUPPLIER_ID]
  HAVING (count(CATEGORY_ID)=  @Count )

--------------- main part ---------------
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly. i just need to concatenate category_ids to @catIds. This works with any number of category_ids. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this programmatic solution as your user input.

```
DECLARE @ids NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'1,2'
DECLARE @input_xml XML = Cast('<root><x>'+ Replace(@ids, ',', '</x><x>')+ '</x></root>' AS XML) 

DECLARE @list_to_table TABLE(Id BIGINT)

INSERT INTO @list_to_table
SELECT DISTINCT f.x.value('.', 'BIGINT') AS Id
FROM @input_xml.nodes('/root/x') f(x);

SELECT sc.supplier_id      
FROM supplier_category sc
INNER JOIN @list_to_table ltt on sc.category_id = ltt.id
GROUP BY sc.supplier_id 
HAVING count(DISTINCT sc.category_id ) = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @list_to_table);
```